# sudo yum install installs only JRE not JDK - Centos

Tags: java-8, centos7, yum

I tried installing open-jdk in Centos using the below command,

```
sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-3.b12.el7_3.x86_64
```

It installs only the JRE by not JDK.

After installation,

1. The folder `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-3.b12.el7_3.x86_64` only jre
2. `javac` is not recognized.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

After going through this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-on-centos-and-fedora), found out that `sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk` installs only JRE.

Executed `sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel` to install JDK.

Comment: This helped me solve a gradle error, on centos, about a missing Tools.jar.  Running my gradle command with an actual JDK fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: dnf install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64 (Fedora)

Comment: after investing 3-4 hour really got the solution appreciated !!!