# OpenJDK 1.8.0 installs jre but not jdk?

Tags: java

I found this older post: [sudo yum install installs only JRE not JDK - Centos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44847659/sudo-yum-install-installs-only-jre-not-jdk-centos)

But when I ran `sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel` I don't see the jdk installed?
I checked;

$ sudo alternatives --config java

There is 1 program that provides 'java'.

### Selection    Command

*+ 1           java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.322.b06-2.el8_5.x86_64/jre/bin/java)

I do devops, not a developer but the devs asked for me to finish the install and get jdk on there, any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not a CentOS user, but I always "install" Java from zip/tar. Uncompress, adjust env JAVA_HOME and PATH. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JDK should be installed after installing this package, you can check with:

```
sudo alternatives --config javac
```

The JRE is just installed inside the `/jre` subdirectory.

Comment: sudo alternatives --config javac

There is 1 program that provides 'javac'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
*+ 1           java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.322.b06-2.el8_5.x86_64/bin/javac)

Comment: does that mean it is installed successfully?

thanks for that, I was using the wrong command to check.. silly me, thank you kindly :)